# Comparing GROUP BY vs. DISTINCT'ing out a Window Function

Tags: sql

I know variations of this question have been asked quite a bit on here, but I wasn't able to find one specifically focused on the performance of DISTINCT when applied to a window function.

Anyhow, my question is, is there any situation in which this formulation of a query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT TEAM, AVG(SCORE) OVER(PARTITION BY TEAM)
FROM TABLE_1;
```

Would perform as well, at least not worse, than

```
SELECT TEAM, AVG(SCORE)
FROM TABLE_1
GROUP BY TEAM;
```

Comment: They aren't equivalent. The first query is simply incorrect, because the window function can only be applied *after* grouping, so either this is an invalid query, or you are using MySQL and don't have `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY`, so it's basically doing `AVG(ANY(SCORE)) OVER (....` which makes no sense. The `DISTINCT` then does nothing because it's already grouped. You *could* in theory get correct results by removing the `GROUP BY 1`, but that would almost certainly be less efficient, because the server probably doesn't realize that `DISTINCT` is working over the same columns as `PARTITION BY`.

Comment: The (perhaps) main difference is that window functions retain all rows, while GROUP BY reduces the number of rows into groups.

Comment: When talking about performance, always add a tag for the dbms you're using. Because different products have (somewhat) different optimizing tricks. I'd expect the optimizer to skip DISTINCT here, because the GROUP BY leaves no duplicates.

Comment: SQL Server seems to create a simpler plan for second query. Simpler is faster, generally speaking.

Comment: @SalmanA You have edited the OP's queries into something different, rendering the existing comments invalid too.

Comment: @GSerg that's correct. The original query was incorrect. Now it works and produces identical results, probably what OP wanted.